# How do I make multiple buttons on drawer handles?

Tags: android

I want a sliding drawer, with two buttons on its handle, unrelated to the ability to slide the drawer. Like the below.

{aOOOb}

where {000} is the handle, and a and b are buttons

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use a layout for the handle that defines the two buttons.

In the example in the [Android Documentation for SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) replace the ImageView for either a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout, then put your buttons inside that layout, and assign that layout as the view for your SlidingDrawer handle as explained in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah I already did that. The handle, even when changed to a linear layout, intercepts all click events and passes pressed state changes down to all children, effectively making any child of the button just a display and not an interactive layout element.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Did you ever discover the correct solution?  This answer obviously won't work for the reasons you describe...